# customize "make install" with automake/autotools

Tags: cgi, autotools, autoconf, automake, build-system

I'm trying to create CGI application in C++ that uses autotools build system. This application will be an interface to my embedded device.
As a result of `make`/`make all` I have `bin` directory with *.cgi executables, previously prepared `html-templates` and `images` directory and lighttpd configuration file.

I need to move my content to proper directories of target device, i.e.:

- all .cgi from bin move to $(wwwdir)/cgi-bin where if not specified than wwwdir would be /var/www/
- `images` directory recursively to the same $(wwwdir) directory
- all of the html templates to $(datarootdir)/$(PACKAGE_NAME)
- lighttpd.conf to $(sysconfdir)

List of my programs is defined like so:
`bin_PROGRAMS=$(top_builddir)/bin/main.cgi`  (here only one main.cgi)

Is there an elegant way to specify installation steps using configure.ac/Makefile.am file so that once user (or some other build system) runs `make install` all files will get where they supposed to?

Currently as a result of `make install`- binary file `main.cgi` lands in `/usr/local/bin/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently as a result of make install- binary file main.cgi lands in /usr/local/bin/.

Yes, that's expected.  You can set this when you run `configure`, e.g.

```
./configure --prefix=/var/www ...
```

should install your `bin_PROGRAMS` to `/var/www/bin`.

In your case, you're going to need to set more:

```
./configure --prefix=/var/www --bindir=/var/www/cgi-bin --sysconfdir=/wherever
```

should set `datarootdir` to `/var/www/share`

Adding your HTML templates to `pkgdata_DATA` should put them in `/var/www/share`*PACKAGE*.  You'll probably need to add an [install hook](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Extending-Installation.html) for your image files since they probably belong in `pkgdata_DATA` too in reality, but are not.

Add lighttpd.conf to `sysconf_DATA`.  I think that covers all your files.

Comment: What about `PACKAGE_NAME` in the question? In my `Makefile.am` I used `@datadir@/@package_name@`, and it was substituted to `${datarootdir}/@package_name@`, which is obviously not correct.